# How do I convert Mat to IplImage in C NOT C++

Tags: c, opencv, matrix

I'm using some old C code that uses the old deprecated `IplImage` type.

I'm using the new OpenCV 2.3.1 for Android, and the images I get from the camera are `CvMat`s.  I want to convert them to `IplImage` so I can pass it to the native function.

Alternatively, I could modify the original function to accept a `CvMat` and convert it to `IplImage` inside the body of the function, but I need to do this in C NOT C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`cvGetImage`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html#getimage):

```
IplImage tmp;
IplImage* result = cvGetImage((CvArr*) mat, &tmp);
```