# opencv: Convert Mat to IplImage Issue

Tags: c++, c, opencv

In my program I have to mix the c++ and c api a bit.

I capture an image with the c api and get one frame:

```
CvCapture* capture = 0; 
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

// some code

IplImage* image = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

Then it is converted to `Mat` to be compatible with the new c++ api and I get a ROI:

```
Mat captureFrame = cvarrToMat(image);

// some code

Mat roi = captureFrame(roiRect);
```

At the end I have to convert the Mat back to IplImage* to work with the c api:

```
IplImage imgCaptureFrame = roi;
```

when I use this as reference &roi I get a

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (svec[j].size == dst.size && svec[j].depth() == d
st.depth() && svec[j].channels() == 1 && i < dst.channels()) in unknown function
, file C:\slave\builds\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\convert.
cpp, line 1306
```

in code using c api.

When I just use

```
IplImage imgCaptureFrame = captureFrame;
```

instead of

```
IplImage imgCaptureFrame = roi;
```

there isn't any error but then I don't have my roi.

What can I do to convert my roi to use it in c api?

Comment: What is the assertion that failed? Do you get a description?

Comment: Added the error information.

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9428938/2065121) helpful?

Answer (score 2):

To convert an `IplImage*` to `cv::Mat` and make an independent copy, do:

```
cv::Mat captureFrame = cv::Mat(image, true);
```

To create a ROI for `captureFrame` you could do something like:

```
cv::Rect roi;
roi.x = 165;
roi.y = 50;
roi.width = 440;
roi.height = 80;

cv::Mat cropped = new cv::Mat(captureFrame, roi);
```

and finally, to do the conversion the other way:

```
IplImage imgCaptureFrame = cropped;
```